# Передача параметров в URL C# ASP

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-core, url, get

В URL передаю строку "FeedBackOverallReport?paramname="value", а туда приходит "FeedBackOverallReport%3FSearchValue%3Dvalue" и параметр в запрос не отправляется ([HttpGet] [FromQuery]). Это происходит ещё на этапе передаче этого значения в location.href. Подскажите, как это можно исправить? Чтоб в URL приходило "FeedBackOverallReport?paramname="value".
Нужно, чтоб значение параметра передалось в контроллер. Если руками прописать "FeedBackOverallReport?paramname="value", то передаётся, а если "FeedBackOverallReport%3FSearchValue%3Dvalue", то нет.

Принцип работы примерно такой:
Есть кнопка по нажатию на которую должен выполнится запрос. У кнопки есть обработчик onclick:

```
<button type="button" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action(`FeedBackOverallReport?SearchValue=ТЕСТ`, `FeedBack`'>Кнопка</button>
```

При нажатии на кнопку происходит переход на метод FeedBackOverallReport в контроллере. параметр SearchValue должен браться из строки, но он не берётся, так как строка меняется на "FeedBackOverallReport%3FSearchValue%ТЕСТ"

Comment: Честно говоря, вообще ничего непонятно, отредактируйте вопрос

Comment: @air2921 , попытался описать понятнее

Comment: Думаю всем было бы понятнее, если бы ты показал код

Comment: @Egor дело в том, что элементы страницы формируются из шаблонов и если я покажу код, то понятнее не станет, придётся объяснять принципы работы шаблонов

Comment: @Egor Привёл пример кода

Comment: Это точно правильный код? У тебя там кавычки не хватает перед ">Кнопка". И вообще, почему бы не использовать нормальные методы JS, а не городить слушатель прямо в HTML?

Comment: @Egor Дело в том, что сделан конструктор для создания однотипных страниц. И там есть параметр для добавления на эти страницы кнопок. Это как раз часть кода из шаблона кнопки, в котором я передаваемые параметры заменил на то, что я передаю. Сделал так, чтоб не описывать всю эту систему конструкторов и шаблонов. Как раз по этому и кавычки не хватает, писал прям тут и пропустил( Способ нормально передавать параметры в запрос используя Url.Action нашёл, немного позже напишу его здесь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<button type="button" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Action", "Controller", new RouteValueDictionary(parametersObject))'"></button>
```

Подробнее о RouteValueDictionary https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.routing.routevaluedictionary?view=aspnetcore-8.0

P.S. написано "на ходу", возможны опечатки, но общая идея такая